# Is there a thread safe way to combine images in C# on an asp.net web app

Tags: c#, .net, graphics, drawing, transparency

I'm looking to write some code that combines three images in a layered order so that transparency at each layer is preserved.  After combining them in memory i want to save the resulting image into a new file.  I heard that .net's system.drawing.2D is not a thread safe way of doing this and would be bad in a server app.  Is there something in .net that I can use to do this?

Comment: Why exactly do you need it to be thread-safe? Because depending on the reason the way to do it may be different.

Comment: In my web app there will be potentially many users logged in using the service to create these images.  I'm not an expert in debugging deadlocks (yet) but it's my understanding that I could be running into them.  I make sure to properly Dispose of objects after using them and haven't had any problems with the simple code I have at the moment but I don't have high concurrent traffic yet as I'm still in private Beta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right to note that `System.Drawing` and all/most? underlying namespaces are unsafe to use in ASP.NET environments. This, at least, is what microsoft claims on the associated MSDN documentation page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xs6ftd89.aspx and in particular:

> Classes within the System.Drawing namespace are not supported for use
>   within a Windows or ASP.NET service. Attempting to use these classes
>   from within one of these application types may produce unexpected
>   problems, such as diminished service performance and run-time
>   exceptions. For a supported alternative, see Windows Imaging
>   Components.

No further details are given in regards to what's the cause of the problem however [this](http://www.asprangers.com/post/2012/03/23/Why-you-should-not-use-SystemDrawing-from-ASPNET-applications.aspx) might give you some more insights.

All in all, the recommended alternative, windows imaging components, is under-documented however there should be enough on google to get you started (start by reading the article linked above, and checkout the referenced articles in the footer).

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look through those.  I recall getting a email a while back asking me for my top ten wishes for things to see in the next version of .Net.  I think I got it from BizSpark or something but I forgot to put "Thread safe graphic manipulation components" in there.

Comment: The problem that usually occurs is that people don't pay attantion to really, really dispose every object which contains a GDI+ handle/pointer of some sort. Almost every object in the `System.Drawing` namespace is disposable, and when properly used with `using` there will be no resources that need to be cleaned up by the finalizer, causing the deadlocks as explained in the linked article. I've done on-line image manipulation (resizing, coloring, combining, drawing with fonts) like this and never encountered an issue when all resources were always properly disposed of. Your mileage may vary...

Comment: @Lucero hear hear however there is also definitive rule in the .NET ecosystem that dispose must be called when available. Furthermore, disposing might only be a part of solutions. Microsoft states that System.Drawing is unsupported in .NET without stating the reason. assuming that the reason is not disposing of resources is a mistake. Especially since Microsoft wont be here to give you support on other issues.

Comment: @Polity, sure there is this rule, but there's plenty of code (and especially also samples) which don't follow this rule and make it into productive code. The example in your link is exactly also due to that. In any case, I've explicitly stated that this is just based on my experience ("your mileage may vary").